# Patent Verification

Tags: patent-applications

Do publication of patent means 'Patent claims' are verified by  US Government?
If a company is sending me the published patent of the technology, can I trust the genuinity of the technology?

Answer (score 2):

No.

Patent applications are published after while (normally 18 months). The USPTO examins the claims if the applicant wants them to, after that the patent application can become a granted patent. That means the claimed inventions are protected from getting used by others. It doesn't mean however, that the technology works (as promised). It just means the examiner thinks it could work. It is not necessary to prove this.

However, if the examiner thinks the claims are not compatible with science he can reject them.